# Bitmap read, write & compare

Tags: vb.net

A) When I write a BMP file & then read it back into another bitmap object the objects appear different. Looks like Horizontal & Vertical Resolutions are changed.

B) When I make the bitmap object resolutions the same the bitmap objects still appear different despite all attributes appearing the same.

C) If I read the same BMP file twice into two different bitmap objects the objects appear different.

Eventually I want to clone small sections of a larger bitmap & ascertain whether I already have a file for the smaller section by comparing against the contents of each known previously generated file in turn. That is, by reading each file as a bitmap I want to be able to compare against the small section bitmap.

I will eventually be placing a checksum in each file's name or attributes for quicker exclusion but will still need to compare each file contents of those who "survive the exclusion" to prevent different files with the same checksum issue.

When run, the code below shows the issues.

```
Private Sub btnTest_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTest.Click
    Dim sFileName As String = "c:\Temp\Red.bmp"

    ' Create red coloured bitmap

    Dim oBitMap1 As New Bitmap(200, 100)
    Dim oGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(oBitMap1)
    oGraphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, 0, 0, 200, 100)

    Dim oBitMapA As New Bitmap(200, 100)
    oBitMapA = oBitMap1
    Debug.Print("oBitMap1 Is oBitMapA = " & CStr(oBitMap1 Is oBitMapA))

    ' Save the bitmap

    oBitMap1.Save(sFileName, Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)

    ' Read the "same" details back into oBitMap2 & BitMap3

    Dim oBitMap2 = New Bitmap(sFileName)
    Dim oBitMap3 = New Bitmap(sFileName)
    'Dim oBitMap2 As Bitmap = Image.FromFile(sFileName)
    'Dim oBitMap3 As Bitmap = Image.FromFile(sFileName)

    ' Show what's what

    Debug.Print("Show whether BitMaps are the same (pre changes)")
    Debug.Print("oBitMap1 Is oBitMap2 = " & CStr(oBitMap1 Is oBitMap2))
    Debug.Print("oBitMap2 Is oBitMap3 = " & CStr(oBitMap2 Is oBitMap3))
    Debug.Print("Show resolutions (pre any changes)")
    Debug.Print("oBitMap1.Resolution  = " & Format(oBitMap1.HorizontalResolution, "##0.###") & "," & Format(oBitMap1.VerticalResolution, "##0.###"))
    Debug.Print("oBitMap2.Resolution  = " & Format(oBitMap2.HorizontalResolution, "##0.###") & "," & Format(oBitMap2.VerticalResolution, "##0.###"))
    Debug.Print("oBitMap3.Resolution  = " & Format(oBitMap3.HorizontalResolution, "##0.###") & "," & Format(oBitMap3.VerticalResolution, "##0.###"))
    oBitMap2.SetResolution(96, 96)
    oBitMap3.SetResolution(96, 96)
    Debug.Print("Show resolutions (post changes)")
    Debug.Print("oBitMap1.Resolution  = " & Format(oBitMap1.HorizontalResolution, "##0.###") & "," & Format(oBitMap1.VerticalResolution, "##0.###"))
    Debug.Print("oBitMap2.Resolution  = " & Format(oBitMap2.HorizontalResolution, "##0.###") & "," & Format(oBitMap2.VerticalResolution, "##0.###"))
    Debug.Print("oBitMap3.Resolution  = " & Format(oBitMap3.HorizontalResolution, "##0.###") & "," & Format(oBitMap3.VerticalResolution, "##0.###"))
    Debug.Print("Show whether BitMaps are the same (post changes)")
    Debug.Print("oBitMap1 Is oBitMap1 = " & CStr(oBitMap1 Is oBitMap1))
    Debug.Print("oBitMap1 Is oBitMap2 = " & CStr(oBitMap1 Is oBitMap2))
    Debug.Print("oBitMap2 Is oBitMap3 = " & CStr(oBitMap2 Is oBitMap3))
End Sub
```

Using descriptions above

A) I'm expecting oBitMap2 read from the file created from oBitMap1 to be the same as oBitMap1 but the resolutions are different.

B) When I set the oBitMap2 resolutions to be the same as oBitMap1 I'm expecting oBitMap1 & oBitmap2 to be the same but they're different.

C) When I read the same file twice I'm expecting the two bitmaps created (oBitMap2 & oBitMap3) to be the same but they're different.

I am wondering whether I've misunderstood the "Is" compare operator or the bitmaps have "hidden" attributes that don't show when I "print" them in the debugger as all the shown attributes appear to be the same.

Comment: This is wrong: `Dim oBitMapA As New Bitmap(200, 100) oBitMapA = oBitMap1`. You could create the new Bitmap using the original as source: `Dim oBitMapA As New Bitmap(oBitMap1)` or clone it: `Dim oBitMapA As Bitmap = CType(oBitMap1.Clone(), Bitmap)`. When you create a new Bitmap without a reference, the DPI defaults to `96` and PixelFormat to `PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb`.

Comment: Hi Jimi. Thanks for getting back to me. The oBitMap1 & BitMapA code was very simply to test the "Is comparative operator".The real issue is why I can't write oBitMap1 to a file & read it back as the same in oBitMap2 plus when I read the same file twice as oBitMap2 & oBitMap3 why are oBitMap2 & oBitMap3 different?

Comment: When you do this: `oBitMapA = oBitMap1`, you assign a reference. When you do this: `Dim oBitMap2 = New Bitmap(sFileName)`, you create a new object. The source file is not relevat, the two objects are not the same: different objects and different references. If you want to compare bitmaps, you need to compare the contents (if you care abount the *physical* equality). You can convert the bitmaps to an array of bytes and use `[Array].SequenceEqual()` to compare the bytes. If you assign an object to another and then compare it, you're actually comparing a reference (a memory address) with itself.